# How Do I Enable Fair Scheduler in PySpark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark

According to the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application)

> Without any intervention, newly submitted jobs go into a default pool, but jobs’ pools can be set by adding the spark.scheduler.pool “local property” to the SparkContext in the thread that’s submitting them

And

> The pool properties can be set by creating an XML file, similar to conf/fairscheduler.xml.template, and either putting a file named fairscheduler.xml on the classpath, or setting spark.scheduler.allocation.file property in your SparkConf

So I can do the first part easily enough:

```
__sp_conf = SparkConf()
__sp_conf.set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
sc = SparkContext(conf=__sp_conf)
sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "default")
```

But how do I get an xml file called `fairscheduler.xml` onto the classpath? Also, the classpath of what? Just the driver? Every executor?

I've tried using the `addFile()` fuction on `SparkContext` but that's really for being able to access files from your jobs, I don't think it adds anything to the classpath.

My other thought was modifying the `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` environment variable to try messing around with the command sent to `spark-submit` but I'm not sure there's a way to alter the classpath using that method. Additionally, this would only alter the classpath of the driver, not every executor which I'm not sure would work or not.

---

To be clear, if I don't provide the `fairscheduler.xml` file Spark complains

> WARN  FairSchedulableBuilder:66 - Fair Scheduler configuration file not found so jobs will be scheduled in FIFO order. To use fair scheduling, configure pools in fairscheduler.xml or set spark.scheduler.allocation.file to a file that contains the configuration.

Comment: `spark-submit --help`; there are several useful options. I think the one you really want is `--properties-file` which allows you to provide an entire properties file - but you could do it with `--conf spark.scheduler.pool=default`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I've set the pool to default already using the spark context `sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "default")`. I need to also somehow provide the `fairscheduler.xml` file or else Spark complains and defaults back to `FIFO` order

Comment: Run the command I provided. You'll see (also) `--files`, you can use that to add "fairscheduler.xml" to each container.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `--files` does the same thing as `sc.addFile` which I've tried and does not work. According to the docs that option is a "Comma-separated list of files to be placed in the working directory of each executor. Globs are allowed." It does not say it puts the files on the root of the classpath which is what needs to happen according to https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5264164a67df498b73facae207eda12ee133be7d/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/SchedulableBuilder.scala#L81

Comment: Did you try `--jars`? These are comments. Maybe someone will answer you.

Answer (score 2):

> Question : But how do I get an xml file called `fairscheduler.xml` onto the
>   classpath? Also, the classpath of what? Just the driver? Every executor?

Below points especially  #4 can help in this case based on the mode you are submitting job.

Here I am trying to list out all...

1. To use the Fair Scheduler first assign the appropriate scheduler class
   in `yarn-site.xml`:

   ```
   <property>
     <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
   ```

   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler
2. your way of `__sp_conf.set` or simply below way can work

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf

   spark.master yarn

   ...
   spark.yarn.dist.files
   /etc/spark/conf/hive-site.xml,/home/hadoop/fairscheduler.xml

   spark.scheduler.mode FAIR
   spark.scheduler.allocation.file fairscheduler.xml
   ```
3. Copy paste fairscheduler.xml in /home/Hadoop/fairscheduler.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <!--Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation
   (ASF) under one or morecontributor license agreements. See the NOTICE
   file distributed withthis work for additional information regarding
   copyright ownership.The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache
   License, Version 2.0(the "License"); you may not use this file except
   in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
   ```

   *http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0* Unless required by
       applicable law or agreed to in writing, softwaredistributed under the
       License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR
       CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.See the License for
       the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the
       License.-->

   ```
   <allocations>
       <pool name="sparkmodule1">
           <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
           <weight>1</weight>
           <minShare>2</minShare>
       </pool>
       <pool name="sparkmodule2">
           <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
           <weight>1</weight>
           <minShare>2</minShare>
       </pool>

   <pool name="test">
       <schedulingMode>FIFO</schedulingMode>
       <weight>1</weight>
       <minShare>2</minShare>
   </pool>
   <pool name="default">
       <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
       <weight>3</weight>
       <minShare>3</minShare>
   </pool>
   </allocations>
   ```

   where sparkmodule1... are the modules to which you want to create dedicated pool of resources.

   **Note**: you don't need to mention default pool like `sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "default")` if no matching pool from your fairscheduler.xml it will go in to default pool naturally.
4. Sample Spark submit like below when you are in cluster mode

   spark-submit --name "jobname" --class
       
       --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster 
       --files  /etc/spark/conf/hive-site.xml,/home/hadoop/fairscheduler.xml

> Note : In client mode if we want to submit a spark job other than
>   home
>           directory with client mode create a symlink of fairscheduler.xml to
>           point to the directory you want to point. for example scripts folder where you are executing spark-submit from 
>           `ln –s /home/Hadoop/fairscheduler.xml fairscheduler.xml`
>
> ***Note :*** If you don't want to copy fairscheduler.xml to /home/hadoop
>   folder you can create fairscheduler.xml under
>   `/etc/spark/conf/fairscheduler.xml` and you can give sym link to the
>   directory where you are executing spark submit like described above.

References : [Spark Fair scheduler example](https://www.supergloo.com/fieldnotes/spark-fair-scheduler-example/)

*To cross verify :*

The [Environment tab](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/configuration.html#runtime-environment) displays the values for the different environment and configuration variables, including Java™, Spark, and system properties. fair allocation file path will be here.

[like...](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-webui-environment.html) 
[image]

Comment: So it does need to be available to every executor?

Comment: AFAIK yes if --deploy-mode cluster

Comment: i dont think for client-mode its needed

Comment: out of my experience if deploy-mode cluster --files was working

Comment: also its nothing specific to pyspark. its at yarn level fair is yarn level. could you remove pyspark from question title ?

Comment: Well I'm specifically looking for an example in pyspark. I know there's like 10 different ways to specify configurations so I was trying to simplify it as much as possible and was hoping there was a way to do it during spark context setup. But it sounds like it is actually a software installation/deployment task. Also, I didn't mention it but we're targeting Mesos not YARN for our resource manager which is why I'm trying to keep the language about what needs access to it resource-manager agnostic.

Comment: "But it sounds like it is actually a software installation/deployment task." yes it is

Answer (score 0):

The following steps we will take:

- Run a simple Spark Application and review the Spark UI History Server.
- Create a new Spark FAIR Scheduler pool in an external XML file.
- Set the *spark.scheduler.pool* to the pool created in external XML file.
- Update code to use threads to trigger use of FAIR pools and rebuild.
- Re-deploy the Spark Application with:

  - *spark.scheduler.mode* configuration variable to FAIR.
  - *spark.scheduler.allocation.file* configuration
- Run and review Spark UI History Server.

REFERENCE

Spark Continuous Application with FAIR Scheduler presentation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXwOQKXo9VE